# I Think I'm on target but why is there an invalid identifier character?

Tags: python, identifier

(This is Python. So sorry for missing that.)

I'm trying to develop a program that calculates the monthly mortgage payments for a given loan amount, term(in number of years) and range of interest rates from 3% to 18%. The formula I was given was:

D = ((1 + r)^(n) – 1)/r(1 + r) ^ n

where A is the the original loan amount, D is the discount, N is the number of payments times 12, and R is the rate as a decimal divided by 12. I understand how the math should work, but how exactly is this all formatted so I can write a bit python code?

I'll get it to print out something like:

interest rate: 3%. Monthly payment: 1475.61. 
interest rate: 4%. Monthly payment: 1670.95. 
interest rate: 5%. Monthly payment: 1878.88. 
interest rate: 6%. Monthly payment: 2098.43. 
and so on down to 18%.

My code so far (that second "1" in the last line is giving me problems by being an invalid character in identifier:

```
#User input is collected
print('enter your loan amount')
a1 = (int(input('amount')))

print ('enter the number of years of the loan')
n1 = (int(input('amount')))

print ('enter the interest rate in decimal format')
r1 = (float(input('rate')))

#Then do the math
n1 * 12 = n

r1 / 12 = r



((1 + r) ** (n) – 1) / r * (1 + r) ** n = D
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't know what programming language you are using.

Comment: Please mention which programming Language you are using ... else we won't be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Python. Very Sorry. Have not used SOF before. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I think you just started to know the word `programming`. You can never do

```
n1*12 = n
r1/12 = r
```

It should only be

```
n = n1 * 12
r = r1 / 12
```

The assigned variable should always be to the left.

Answer (score 0):

With respect, I'm not sure that you understand the math either. Or maybe I don't. The formula you give doesn't even include a term "A", so I don't understand what "where A is the original loan amount" means, or what the "discount" is supposed to be.

The [classic mortgage loan payment formula](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Mortgage-Payments) is:

```
M = P [ r(1+r)^n ] / [ (1+r)^n - 1 ]
```

where

- **P** is the principal amount on the loan
- **r** is the monthly interest rate
- **n** is the number of payments

So once you have gotten these values into variables `P`, `r` and `n`, a Python expression to calculate the monthly mortgage payment M would be:

```
M = P * ( r * (1 + r) ** n ) / ((1 + r) ** n - 1)
```

Comment: These were the original instructions:

Develop and test a Python program that calculates the monthly mortgage payments for a given loan amount, term(number of years) and range of interest rates from 3% to 18%. The fundamental formula for determining this is A/D, where A is the original loan amount, and D is the discount factor. The discount factor is calculated as,


D = ((1 + r)^(n) – 1)/r(1 + r) ^ n

Where n is the number of total payments(12 times the number of years of the loan) and r is the interest rate, expressed in decimal format (e.g.,.05), divided by 12.

Comment: Even though they weren't in the original formula, the intended values were explained....

Comment: All of this has me quite confused for some reason. I finally got the identifier errors to stop, but I still have a ways to go to get it tio generate a list for 3-18%...

Comment: Okay. So given the formula you described for D, calculating A/D should give you the monthly mortgage payment. That at least jibes with other mortgage calculators.